# Problem with Silverlight 3 plugin on FireFox

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I recently upgraded to SilverLight 3 (beta) and for some reason the SilverLight plug in will not view local SilverLight Projects, i.e. when I hit F5 (debug) I can see the page loading, but then nothing happens.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it turned out to be an old version of the Toolkit dll, specifically the autocompletebox.  It was compiling fine, but threw the runtime error every time it would try to load.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the new beta yet, so I can't help you much, but it's possible that the old Silverlight plugin and the new beta plugin are conflicting. Try fully uninstalling both plugins and then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it wasn't the FireFox plugin.  For whatever reason the Silverlight 3 plugin is more strict than the Silverlight 2 plugin, and when debugging the project it will choke on displaying the app due to the as of now unfound error.